# How to delete 1 of 2 data ranges for an existing chart using App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

For some context, I have a chart with originally 1 data range, which my existing macro adds a second data range to.

I now want to delete the charts original data range, so that it is only displaying the new data range. Is this possible to do via Google App Script?

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example of what you've already done - your question lacks detail for us to be able to help (I doubt you really want a "yes" answer :) That said, if you are talking about embedded charts, have you tried `removeRange(range)`?

Comment: How about [the pattern 2 in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60226424) for your latest question? In this case, the existing ranges are replaced with the new range. If I misunderstood your goal of this question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explicitly answer this question I copied @Tanaike portion of the answer that solves your issue.

### Pattern

```js
var daily_data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Daily Data");
var LTD_data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Long Term Data");

var chart = daily_data.getCharts()[0];
var range = LTD_data.getRange("B2:J3")

var ranges = chart.getRanges();
chart = chart.modify();
ranges.forEach(function(range) {chart.removeRange(range)});
var modifiedChart = chart.addRange(range).build();
daily_data.updateChart(modifiedChart);
```

### References:

- [updateChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#updatechartchart)
- [removeRange(range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#removerangerange)